# counting non-zero values from a list with scheme

Tags: scheme

I am new at scheme and at this site.. I interrupt with this question. please give me a way to write a scheme function to calculate how many non-zero values are there in a list of numbers..

> (non-zero '(4 1 0 2 0 1 3)) - 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider three cases:

```
(define (non-zero numbers)
  (cond ((null? numbers) 0)              ; is the list empty? return zero
        ((not (= (car numbers) 0))       ; is the current element non-zero?
         (+ 1 (non-zero (cdr numbers)))) ; add 1 to the counter and recur
        (else                            ; otherwise
         (non-zero (cdr numbers)))))     ; skip to the next element
```

Or if your interpreter supports it, a more idiomatic solution would be to use higher-order procedures:

```
(define (non-zero numbers)
  (count (lambda (n) (not (zero? n)))
         numbers))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(non-zero '(4 1 0 2 0 1 3))
=> 5
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with scheme at all. But this can easily be implemented using recursion. Imagine a list [0,1,2,2,0,1]. You would need to walk down the list, looking at each element in turn and increasing a counter by one each time you find a 0 in the list.

```
(define (count_zeroes numbers)
  (if (null? numbers) 0
      (+ 1 (count_zeroes (cdr numbers))))
```

Comment: yeah thanks.. But in here where we check the condition which is the atom is a non-zero value? (for checking that as a zero we use (= 0 (car numbers))), that is why I confused, How we check the atom is non-zero?